# Change Context root for the application deployed in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

This is my web.xml

```
<display-name>Schedule_FTP</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>main.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>


 <servlet>      
    <servlet-name>Schedule_FTP</servlet-name>   
     <jsp-file>/Schedule_FTP/main.jsp</jsp-file>  
 </servlet>  

     <servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>Schedule_FTP</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/Schedule_FTP/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

Basically Main.jsp invokes a java class.

When I reload the applciation in tomcat manager url. It get the message as below.

```
            OK - Reloaded application at context path /Schedule_FTP
```

I want this to be,  - context path /Schedule_FTP/main.jsp

Can somebody please help me to undesrtand what am i missing?

Server details: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47,  JVM Version 1.6.0_35-b10

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add an additional url pattern to your servlet mapping :

```
 <servlet>      
    <servlet-name>Schedule_FTP</servlet-name>   
     <jsp-file>/Schedule_FTP/main.jsp</jsp-file>  
 </servlet>  

     <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>Schedule_FTP</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/Schedule_FTP/main.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/Schedule_FTP/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Hi Joel, Thank you! It didnt help me. but im able to achive what i need for now.